# How to debug Infopath 2010 web form?

Tags: infopath

Well, in visual studio 2008 we were able to create infopath 2007 web form project and after that attach to iis process to debug infopath web form.

In visual studio 2010 there is not infopath project and we can use only vsto and cant attach to iis process.

So, how to debug Infopath 2010 web form? - is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The process for debugging InfoPath 2010 form templates with code behind has changed quite a bit from InfoPath 2007 thanks to Microsoft not letting us develop our stuff in Visual Studio anymore :-)

Actually there is a really nice MSDN article about [Investigating Issues with InfoPath 2010 SharePoint Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg271285.aspx#IP14_Debugging) which will surely help you!

There are several things you need to do to enable your forms for debugging (all done in the InfoPath code editor or Visual Studio Tools for Applications):

1. Build in Debug mode (Project Properties > Build > Active (Debug)
2. Enable full Debug Info (Project Properties > Build > Advanced)
3. Clear "Enable Just My Code" and select "Suppress JIT..." (Tools > Options > Debugging)

Then you can deploy your template and attach to either the correct `w3wp` process or the `SPUCWorkerProcess` for a sandboxed solution - for this you will need to use Visual Studio.

In any case: Make sure you read the MSDN article ;-)

Comment: +1 I am surprised that this answer is un(der)voted in comparison to compltely unrelated to question another one

Answer (score 0):

From Visual Studio 2010, have you tried opening a project you created in visual studio 2008? You can still attach to the iis process from vs 2010, though officially, I didn't think SharePoint 2007 was supported in Vs 2010.

If that doesn't work, you can always [install vs 2008 side by side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx) with 2010.